# How to assign text to cell in tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a taskList application in swift and my code is :

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView : UITableView!
    var textField : UITextField!
    var tableViewData = ["My Text 1", "My Text 2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set up textField

        self.textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))
        self.textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.textField)

        //Set up table view

        self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-100), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)


    }
    //TableView Data source Delegate

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return tableViewData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let myNewCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        //Here is the error
        myNewCell.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]

        return myNewCell
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
'text' is unavailable:APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift
```

I am doing this from tutorial and that person used xCode 6.0 and I have xCode 6.1 beta Version I think that is the problem because I am using beta version.
Can anybody explain me what is this error and I am new in swift so can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
myNewCell.textLabel?.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
```

it used to be:

```
myNewCell.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
```

but they embedded the text property in a textLabel property.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
myNewCell.textLabel?.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call textLabel and textLabel is optional so you need to unwrap it:

```
if let textLabel = myNewCell.textLabel {
    textLabel.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
}
```

or

```
myNewCell.textLabel?.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]
```